# I'm using the Selenium Webdriver gem to try to click on the facebook chat bar, sometimes it work and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: ruby, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the Selenium Webdriver gem to try to click on the facebook chat bar, sometimes it work and sometimes it doesn't. When it does not work it returns the Selenium Element not visible error, but it clearly is visible. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome # instantiates a google chrome session
driver.navigate.to 'https://www.facebook.com/' # takes you to facebook.com

emailBar = driver.find_element(:id,"email") #finds email input bar
passwordBar = driver.find_element(:id,"pass") #find password input bar
loginButton = driver.find_element(:id,"u_0_n") #finds login button

emailBar.send_keys "austinspreadsheet@gmail.com" # puts in the email
passwordBar.send_keys "YOURPASSWORD" # puts in the password
loginButton.click # clicks the login button

#THIS IS THE CODE BLOCK THAT DOES NOT WORK 
links = driver.find_elements(:class,"fbNubButton") # finds the chat bar
#driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 10
links[0].click # opens the chat bar
links[1].click # NOTE that sometime it clicks and sometimes it doesn't but if you click both chat box classes it usually works, so the error is ok
```

I have tried not clicking both chat links and it works less when I do that.

Comment: I too faced problems like that. I would suggest you to use `sleep (5)` before clicking . 5 secs would be enough for the DOM to be ready.

Comment: Hey guys, I just used the expand page function to make the page large enough so facebook friends would show up automatically on the side of the page.
    driver.manage.window.resize_to(1300,940)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Selenium with Python. In case like yours the issue is related to waiting until all the elements in the page are full loaded.

The basic behavior of Selenium offers you Explicit and Implicit Waits. So basicly you can force the system to wait a default number of second or wait until an element is loaded.

From Selenium documentation (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

**Explicit wait**

An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The worst case of this is Thread.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period to wait. There are some convenience methods provided that help you write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be accomplished.

```
require 'rubygems' # not required for ruby 1.9 or if you installed without gem
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
begin
  element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element") }
ensure
  driver.quit
end
```

**Implicit wait**

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

```
require 'rubygems' # not required for ruby 1.9 or if you installed without gem
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds

driver.get "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading"
element = driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I use it in newer parts of the code, such as to wait until facebook friends are loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that aberna gives you on this thread has a lot of great information but it isn't going to solve your issue.   If you use the Explicit wait method that aberna suggests, you also probably need to make sure the element is visible.   Using .findElements on its own doesn't guarantee clickability/visibility .  You could try to use expectedconditions .visibilityOfElementLocated  which will also check for visibility as well as presence.

Or, alternatively, you can check for presence of the element on the DOM using .findElement  but then use the expectedconditions.visibilityOf to check for the visibility part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sleep(5)  before run main logic

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Solution that worked for me was to maximise my browser window. This solved many of failing specs.

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
```